# How to find just below elements by selector in enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I use enzyme + jest to test our react application.

How to find just below elements by selector if rendered html has nested same structure?

I want to parent two `button` elements if `render` method returns following HTML.

```
<ul>
  <li><button ...>parent1</button></li>
  <li><button ...>parent2</button>
    <ul>
      <li><button ...>child1</button></li>
      <li><button ...>child2</button></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In enzyme 2.7.1, I can get parent two `button` elements by `> ul > li > button` selector like following code.
(uh... it's obviously weird selector. but it did work)

```
const component = shallow(<Sample {...props}/>)
const parentButtons = component.find('> ul > li > button')
expect(parentButtons.length).toBe(2)
```

But in enzyme 3.3.0 occur an "Failed to parse selector" error.

#### I tried...

- `ul > li > button` returns all buttons which contain child buttons, it makes sense.
- `:root` pseudo selector, it isn't supported enzyme yet.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Why not to use classes? And what is the structure of DOM at least one level above the upper `<ul>`?

Comment: Yes, I can add class for workaround. but IMO, we shouldn't change product code for ONLY unittest as far as possible.

Comment: The root node of returned DOM is `<ul>` in this component. This component will be used in other `<div>` or else, but it does not affect in shallow rendering in unittest.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that given DOM structure won't change (at least that `parent` buttons will always be first nodes of top `li`'s) this should work:

```
const parentButtons = component.find('ul').first().children().map(child => child.childAt(0));
const parentButtonsTexts = component.find('ul').first().children().map(child => child.childAt(0).text());

expect(parentButtons).toHaveLength(2);
expect(parentButtonsTexts).toEqual(['parent1', 'parent2']);
```